# AsyncTask и пользовательский Listener. Переменные не умирают

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

У меня есть список. При нажатии на элемент списка, должен запускаться `AsyncTask`. Прогресс передается к фрагменту через интерфейс:

```
public interface OnFileDownloadListener {
    void onStartDownloading(String title);
    void onProgress(int progress);
    void onDonwloadingComplete();
    void onError();
}
```

В методе `getView` адаптера, обрабатываю нажатие, для запуска асинхронной задачи.

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + ": click ");
            checked = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (translationDownloadTask != null) {
                translationDownloadTask.cancel(true);
            }
            translationDownloadTask = new TranslationDownloadTask(translations[position], translations[position]);
            translationDownloadTask.setListener(listener);
            //Listener это мой фрагмент. Передаю его через конструктор.
            translationDownloadTask.execute();
        }
    });
```

В `AsyncTask` вызываю методы интерфейса чтобы передавать события. В качестве слушателя этих событий адаптеру передаю фрагмент.

Вот самое важное из жизни фрагмента:

```
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState!=null){
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(CHECKED_POSITION)){
            checked = savedInstanceState.getInt(CHECKED_POSITION);
            adapter.setChecked(checked);
        }
    }
    progressShowing = false;
}


@Override
public void onStartDownloading(String title) {
    progressShowing = true;
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onProgress(String title, int progress) {
    dialog.setProgress(progress);
}

@Override
public void onDonwloadingComplete() {}

@Override
public void onError() {}
```

Проблема в том, что если `AsyncTask` запустить, то переменная `progressShowing`  после поворота экрана остается true**, хотя в `onViewStateRestored` я задаю ей значение `false`. **Объясните поведение переменной и причину, почему она меняется на true.

Comment: Как Вы передаете это из AsyncTask? И если идет процесс загрузки, зачем указывать false?

Comment: Зачем указывать false это мое дело. Главное что не указывается. Из AsyncTask передаю вызовом методов интерфейса в нужных местах.